# Spring security jsf not redirecting after successsfull login

Tags: jsf, redirect, spring-security

I have seen questions like this, but I have not seen an answer for my specific question.

I am using spring security 2.1 and jsf 2.1.  I have a custom jsf login controler that I develop to handle login from xhtml file.

Here is login method:

```
public String login() throws ServletException, IOException {

    ExternalContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
            .getExternalContext();

    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = ((ServletRequest) context.getRequest())
            .getRequestDispatcher("/j_spring_security_check");

    dispatcher.forward((ServletRequest) context.getRequest(),
            (ServletResponse) context.getResponse());

    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();

    Exception e = (Exception) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().
              getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get(WebAttributes.AUTHENTICATION_EXCEPTION);




    // It's OK to return null here because Faces is just going to exit.
    return null;

}
```

I pulled the example code from another post.

Here is my spring configuration:

```
    <http use-expressions="true" auto-config="true">
    <!-- <intercept-url pattern="/signin.xhtml" access="permitAll" /> -->

    <intercept-url pattern="/internal/private/**" access="hasRole('USER')" />
    <!-- <intercept-url pattern="/scheduling/internal/private/**" access="hasAnyRole('ADMIN','USER')" 
        /> -->
    <!--<intercept-url pattern="/javax.faces.resource/**" access="permitAll"/> 
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll" /> -->

    <form-login default-target-url="/internal/private/landing.xhtml"
        login-page="/signin.xhtml" />
</http>
```

As you can see my default target URL is "/internal/private/landing.xhtml".  I have debug turned on and can see that authentication has passed, but is never redirected to default page.

Here is a snipped from the log that shows redirection call from Spring:

```
    08:58:03,701 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionFixationProtectionStrategy] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2) Invalidating session with Id 'qPg2MdmRgSpTcV6CVT7cb-9M.undefined' and migrating attributes.
08:58:03,703 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionFixationProtectionStrategy] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2) Started new session: GFoQyvUtbd+lmZiNw0QKRrI-.undefined
08:58:03,705 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2) Authentication success. Updating SecurityContextHolder to contain: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@d9fa0ad7: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@da682271: Username: roland.jones; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ADMIN,USER; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffe3f86: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: qPg2MdmRgSpTcV6CVT7cb-9M.undefined; Granted Authorities: ADMIN, USER
08:58:03,714 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2) Using default Url: /internal/private/landing.html
08:58:03,716 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2) Redirecting to '/scheduling/internal/private/landing.html'
08:58:03,718 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2) SecurityContext stored to HttpSession: 'org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@d9fa0ad7: Authentication: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@d9fa0ad7: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@da682271: Username: roland.jones; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ADMIN,USER; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffe3f86: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: qPg2MdmRgSpTcV6CVT7cb-9M.undefined; Granted Authorities: ADMIN, USER'
08:58:03,727 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2) SecurityContext stored to HttpSession: 'org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@d9fa0ad7: Authentication: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@d9fa0ad7: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@da682271: Username: roland.jones; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ADMIN,USER; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffe3f86: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: qPg2MdmRgSpTcV6CVT7cb-9M.undefined; Granted Authorities: ADMIN, USER'
08:58:05,156 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2) Chain processed normally
```

After I try to login, if I type in the default URL in the address it goes there no problem, so I know authentication passed.

Please help.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Spring Security 3.x, you can achieve it using an [authentication handler](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AuthenticationSuccessHandler.html), which allows you writing your custom servlet code to manage a successful authentication. I know you are using Spring Security 2 but if upgrading is an option you can consider it.

I firstly declare the login form for the access and make it available for every user. Appart from that, I leave the rest of the urls restricted:

```
<http use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/login**" access="permitAll()" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/home"
        always-use-default-target="false" 
        authentication-success-handler-ref="authenticationSuccessHandler"
        authentication-failure-handler-ref="authenticationFailureHandler" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/login" invalidate-session="true" />
</http>
```

Notice I declare two authentication handlers, the **success** and the **failure** ones. After that, I have my own `SystemAuthenticationSuccessHandler` implemented, which provides me the capability of executing servlet code once the authentication is successfully done:

```
<beans:bean id="authenticationSuccessHandler"
    class="com.mycompany.security.SystemAuthenticationSuccessHandler" />
```

With that I'm able to perform a redirection if the authentication is successfully permormed:

```java
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationSuccessHandler;

public class SystemAuthenticationSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest req, 
        HttpServletResponse res, Authentication auth) 
        throws IOException, ServletException {
            res.sendRedirect(req.getContextPath() + "/home");
    }

}
```

Comment: So I am actually using Spring Security 3.1 and I created a custom success handler like the one above and still doesn't redirect.  Is there another configuration I need to make.

Comment: Thanks for you help, but I figured it out.  I was using a Primefaces button and for some reason Spring doesn't like that.  When I changed to a regular jsf button it worked fine.  May I will put in an issue to Spring about this.